# Laptop shuts down when placed on top of another laptop

Tags: shutdown, dell-xps

I can reproduce this 100% reliably. We have two Dell XPS 13 laptops, both running Ubuntu. If one is placed on top of the other (the bottom one is closed, the top one is open), the one on top will shut down. If we restart it, it will shut down again within a minute or two. The two computers are the same model. All it takes to make the shutdown happen is for one computer to be on top of the other—no other action needed. There must be *some* communication going on between them, but what? And why is the top one shutting down? Any ideas?

Comment: Its a thermal issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like its a magnet in one unit is triggering a reed switch in the other one - https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-acting-as-magnet/td-p/7416219